# Ibeacon Navigation Controller and ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Hi I am a beginner in stackoverflow and swift.
I have a question about Ibeacon in swift.
I follow this [Tutorial](http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14702963-getting-started-developing-ibeacon-apps-with-swift-on-apple-ios-7-8) and work.

Unfortunately, I want to add a Navigation Controller, and there is an issue I can't solve it.

In storyboard, I embed in Navigation Controller and set Storyboard Entry Point.

```
    let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
    viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
    viewController.tableView!.reloadData()
```

show:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x3439285c) to 'Ibeacon.ViewController' (0xda2e8).

Ok, I Google for it,and I try :

```
    let storyboard :UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController : ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Ibeacon_menu") as! ViewController 
    viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
    viewController.tableView!.reloadData()
```

It still not working......

Ok, I open debug mode to see its value.

I found beacons and tableView are nil.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Please Help me!! Thanks.

Comment: let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
this is wrong. Since your entry point is UINavigationController, it should be navigation controller

Comment: But beacon and tableView paras are in ViewController. Do I need to create a new navigation controller~?

Comment: Where you are trying this, which class and method?

Comment: In AppDelegate.swift extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
code here.
}
and beacon and tableView in ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing in appdelegate didfinishLoading, then try it

```
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! ViewController
viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
viewController.tableView!.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!  It  work!!!
But I don't know
navigationController.viewControllers[0]  its mean.
Could you please explain it?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Navigation controller is like stack, which will contain view controller's. So the property viewControllers will give you all view controller's in that stack. Since stack follow's LIFO, your root view controller will be at first position and you need to pass 0 as index to get the root object.

Comment: Bravo!! Very precise answer!
But I want to know why my second answer is wrong.  {
let storyboard :UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController : ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Ibeacon_menu") as! ViewController }

Answer (score 0):

@Amit89 Can you sometimes explain this also in Objective-C. I'm currently having the same problem with that navigationcontroller which is not the rootviewcontroller.